# How to use "kubectl -l/--selector" to scale a specific pod in a deployment in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I want to scale in a pod with a specific label, but it seems -l does not work for scaling.

For example, if I have pods bla-12345-aaaaa, bla-12345-bbbbb, and bla-12345-cccc, and I scale in to 2 replicas, I want bla-12345-aaaaa specifically to disappear.

I get this error:

```
kubectl scale --replicas=2 deployment/bla -l scaleIn=true
error: selectors and the all flag cannot be used when passing resource/name arguments
```

You can see it in the documentation:

> -l, --selector='': Selector (label query) to filter on, supports '=', '==', and '!='.(e.g. -l key1=value1,key2=value2)

Comment: You can't "scale a pod"; all of the pods managed by a deployment are identical, and they're the lowest unit of scheduling.  If you already know the deployment name, why do you want to also pass a label?

Comment: @DavidMaze, I meant I want to scale in a specific pod in a deployment. Edited the title now

Comment: Say `deployment/bla` currently has three replicas; let's call them `bla-12345-aaaaa`, `bla-12345-bbbbb`, and `bla-12345-ccccc`.  What do you want the final state to be?  (The three pods will pretty much definitionally have the same labels.)

Comment: @DavidMaze, I edited the post. Can I only use labels to choose a deployment to scale? Can I not label a specific pod to remove when scaling in a deployment?

Comment: All of the pods will have the same labels.

Comment: [Kubernetes scale down specific pods](/questions/33617090/kubernetes-scale-down-specific-pods) talks about this, but in the context of ReplicaSets (and even then says it’s impossible).  This is harder when Deployments manage ReplicaSets and the suggestion in the first answer won’t work.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the below command

```
kubectl scale  deployment/bla --replicas=2
```

Note: You cant scale pods. you can scale replicaSets/Deployments/StatefulSets

Follow the below steps to scale deployment by label

```
[root@f482a0035623 work]# kubectl get deploy -l app=web   
NAME     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
webapp   1/1     1            1           88d
[root@f482a0035623 work]# kubectl scale deploy -l app=web --replicas=2
deployment.extensions/webapp scaled
[root@f482a0035623 work]# kubectl get deploy -l app=web
NAME     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
webapp   2/2     2            2           88d
```

Comment: I want to scale a specific pod, and it seems like labeling is only available solution

Answer (score 2):

Like [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) said, you cannot scale pods.

You can check that by doing `kubectl scale explain`:

> Examples:
>
> ## Scale a replicaset named 'foo' to 3.
>
> `kubectl scale --replicas=3 rs/foo`
>
> ## Scale a resource identified by type and name specified in "foo.yaml" to 3.
>
> `kubectl scale --replicas=3 -f foo.yaml`
>
> ## If the deployment named mysql's current size is 2, scale mysql to 3.
>
> `kubectl scale --current-replicas=2 --replicas=3 deployment/mysql`
>
> ## Scale multiple replication controllers.
>
> `kubectl scale --replicas=5 rc/foo rc/bar rc/baz`
>
> ## Scale statefulset named 'web' to 3.
>
> `kubectl scale --replicas=3 statefulset/web`

Also you can read in the documentation [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/).

> The Horizontal Pod Autoscaler automatically scales the number of pods in a replication controller, deployment or replica set based on observed CPU utilization (or, with [custom metrics](https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/custom-metrics-api.md) support, on some other application-provided metrics). Note that Horizontal Pod Autoscaling does not apply to objects that can’t be scaled, for example, DaemonSets.

You can target the `deployment` to scale in 2 ways. One is to provide a name of the deployment like so:

`kubectl scale --replicas=2 deployment/bla`

or targeting it with a label:

`kubectl scale deploy -l scaleIn=true --replicas=2`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following format:

```
kubectl scale --replicas=2 deployment -l scaleIn=true
```

It will scale all the deployment that match the label selector.

Comment: It makes sense, but instead I get
error: no objects passed to scale

Comment: @Crou putting deployment_name will give him the same error. If you're giving the name, then what is the necessary of label selector.

Comment: @surimisticks, It will match the labels of the deployment instead of pods. Does your deployment contain `scaleIn=true` label?